# How to switch rails 3 migration generation to timestamps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically is there a way to use time stamps instead of sequential migration generation in rails 3?

Comment: Custom migration generator can help you i guess.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186549/how-to-override-rails-default-migration-generator-template
You can replace `migration_template @migration_template, "db/migrate/#{Time.now}.rb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the generated migration files have timestamps in the names. Looks like someone has turned that off in your project. Look in your config files for this:

```
config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = false
```

Either change it to true or take it out completely. For reference, see this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/migrations.html#what-s-in-a-name